# Upload files to attach and then attach them to mail with phpmailer and jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, email

Well my problem is this:

I want to successfully upload 2 files to my server and then send an email attaching this 2 files. But when i call the jquery function it only send the email before it successfuly upload and i don't get any attach. I want to wait untill the upload it's done and then send the email with the 2 files correctly attached. By the way im using PHPmailer.

I have this html

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="formulario2">
 <label for="cel" class="control-label">Presentación Corporativa</label>
 <div class="controls">
  <input type="file" name="file_name2" id="presentacion_web"                                                                          class="inputfile">
  <label for="presentacion_web" class="btn btn-primary">Elija un Archivo</label>
  <input id="nombre_archivo2" disabled>
  <div class="messages2"></div><br /><br />
 </div> 
</form>


<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="formulario">
 <label for="dni" class="control-label">Diseño Aprobado</label>
 <div class="controls">
  <input type="file" name="file_name1" id="diseno_aprobado_web" class="inputfile">
  <label for="diseno_aprobado_web" class="btn btn-primary">Elija un Archivo</label>
  <input id="nombre_archivo1" disabled>
  <div class="messages"></div><br /><br />
 </div>
</form>
```

this function in jquery:

```
$var3 = $("#diseno_aprobado_web").val();
$var6 = $("#presentacion_web").val();
$var7 = $var3.substring(12);
$var8 = $var6.substring(12);
$.when( enviando1(), enviando2() ).then( function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: ('var3='+$var7+'&var6='+$var8),
            url: 'send_mail.php',
            success: function(salida){
                alert('Mensaje Enviado');
            }
        });


    }).done( function(){
        console.log( ' Everything was OK!' );
      })
      .fail( function(){
        console.log( 'Something was failed' );
      });
function enviando1(){
    var formData = new FormData($(".formulario")[0]);
    var message = ""; 
    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload.php',  
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function(){
            message = $("<span class='before'>Subiendo el archivo, por favor espere...</span>");
            showMessage(message); 
        },
        success: function(data){
            message = $("<span class='success'>El archivo ha subido correctamente.</span>");
            showMessage(message);
        },
        error: function(){
            message = $("<span class='error'>Ha ocurrido un error.</span>");
            showMessage(message);
        }
    });
};
    function showMessage(message){
        $(".messages").html("").show();
        $(".messages").html(message);
    }
function enviando2(){
    var formData2 = new FormData($(".formulario2")[0]);
    var message2 = "";   
    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload2.php',  
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData2,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function(){
            message2 = $("<span class='before'>Subiendo el archivo, por favor espere...</span>");
            showMessage2(message2);        
        },
        success: function(data){
            message2 = $("<span class='success'>El archivo ha subido correctamente.</span>");
            showMessage2(message2);
        },
        error: function(){
            message2 = $("<span class='error'>Ha ocurrido un error.</span>");
            showMessage2(message2);
        }
    });
};
    function showMessage2(message2){
        $(".messages2").html("").show();
        $(".messages2").html(message2);
    }
```

And this php file (send_mail.php) :

```
    require('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
$bodytext = "Correct Message";

$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'test@mydomain.com';
$email->FromName  = 'test bot';
$email->Subject   = 'New mail from phpmailer';
$email->Body      = $bodytext;
$email->AddAddress( 'test2@test2.com' );

$file_to_attach1 = 'folder/' . $_POST['var6'];
$file_to_attach2 = 'folder/' . $_POST['var3'];

$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach1 , $_POST['var6'] );
$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach2 , $_POST['var3'] );


      return $email->Send();
```

I was trying a lot of code and i'm really stuck and frustrated now. Sorry if is something simple but i couldn't get an answer to my problem.

Thanks!

Update1:

I found this in my upload.php, and i think it's the problem:

```
$file = $_FILES['file_name']['name'];
if ($file && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_name']['tmp_name'],"folder/".$file))
{
   sleep(3);
   echo $file;
}
```

This is returning a success in my ajax after 3 seconds, how i can turn this

> "sleep(3)"

Into the time required to upload the file?.

Update 2:

upload.php

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'){

$file = $_FILES['file_name1']['name'];

if(!is_dir("folder")) 
    mkdir("folder", 0777);

if ($file && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_name1']['tmp_name'],"folder/".$file)){
   sleep(3);
   echo $file;
}}else{    throw new Exception("Error Processing Request", 1);  }
```

upload2.php

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'){

$file = $_FILES['file_name2']['name'];

if(!is_dir("folder")) 
    mkdir("folder", 0777);

if ($file && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_name2']['tmp_name'],"folder/".$file))
{
   sleep(3);
   echo $file;
}}else{    throw new Exception("Error Processing Request", 1);}
```

Comment: Do you see the files you upload on the server?

Comment: You should also check if uploaded files gets saved in server. As phpMailer should be able to handle both absolute paths and relative paths to your script. What will var_dump(file_exists(\__DIR\__ . '/' . $file_to_attach1)); will say?

Comment: Yes but sometimes it send the email before the upload is done, maybe it's something with the size of the file.

Comment: The names are dynamic, first i upload 2 random files and then i want to attach them in a new email.

Comment: Can you show me upload.php and upload2.php

Comment: I will edit the post with that files. That 2 files are the problem i think.

Comment: In your javascript name's are not dynamic. those are defined as $var6 = 'FileName1'; $var3 = 'FileName2'; Assumeing those upload.php and upload2.php files should report file names back, so in your ajax success callbacks you should give those variables real uploaded file names

Comment: @Aivar that is what I am noticing as well

Comment: $_FILES['file_name']['name']; cannot be correct either should be $_FILES['presentacion_web_nombre']['name']; And sleep in upload.php is also not needed

Comment: It's just examples names, i'm getting names of input from $var3 = ("#upload_input").val();

Comment: Getting file names from input may give you wrong names and paths, example in chrome C:\fakepath\filename.ext, in this case you need to remove path

Comment: I'm using $var3 = $var3.substring(12); I'm getting the right names btw in both cases.

Comment: There is also missing returns in your enviando and enviando2 functions before $.ajax. There should be "return $.ajax({.." - otherwise your callback will be called before ajax calls are ended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add return's

You have:

```
 function enviando1(){
        var formData = new FormData($(".formulario")[0]);
        var message = "";
        $.ajax({
```

Must be:

```
 function enviando1(){
        var formData = new FormData($(".formulario")[0]);
        var message = "";
        return $.ajax({
```

You have:

```
function enviando2(){
        var formData2 = new FormData($(".formulario2")[0]);
        var message2 = "";
        $.ajax({
```

Must be:

```
function enviando2(){
        var formData2 = new FormData($(".formulario2")[0]);
        var message2 = "";
        return $.ajax({
```

Comment: In each case what ajax i should put? I'm not really getting it.

Comment: He is using variables to store the file names. Why does he need a return? The script waits for these to finish already. In the end there is really nothing being used in these.

Comment: @nerdlyist Nope, script do not wait, as $.when accepts deferreds objects not functions, and this is why send mail gets called too soon right after both function's has been called, but not yet ended.

Comment: AWESOME! That's the answer! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Aivar something learned! Then would this be a mashup of this and my suggestion? Could he use these returned ajax calls to get the file name in the when function call rather then making the variables?

Comment: This will help me also in a lot of stuff. This was like my final boss in ajax. Thanks again!

Comment: @nerdlyist actually he could use when and remove those variables if he would like - this would be a lot more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try **.done** instead of **.then** in the following line of your code

```
$.when( enviando1(), enviando2() ).then( function(){
```

The method will resolve its **.done** request as soon as all the request resolve **(enviando1(),enviando1())**, or reject the **.done** request as soon as one of the request is rejected.

Comment: I just try it and it's the same. I'll keep trying other things. Thanks btw.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use dynamic file name but have $var3 and $var6 static. Use this to get the name of the file being uploaded.

```
$var6 = $(presentacion_web).val().split('\\').pop();
$var3 = $(diseno_aprobado_web).val().split('\\').pop();
```

Comment: I have no problems with the name of the files. I'm getting the correct name of the files uploaded and i already tested with alerts.

Comment: You may be uploading the correct ones but are you attaching the correct ones? The var you pass in are FileName1 and FileName2. If you use just .val() that is not correct either. You will want to get the file name and build the path that is on the server.

Comment: @MiguelRamirez yes and I would suggest attempting this. You stated using substring(12) but that may not be correct as well as the file name could be longer or shorter.

Comment: Well i was trying uploading a lot of differents files with different names and using substring(12) it gave me the correct name of all.

Comment: It may do that some of the time but it is a gamble and could lead to bugs down the road. This will give you just the filename and the you can using it in send_mail.php to build a path to the correct file.